# A palavra "cincoenta" existe?

Tags: ortografia, números

Certa vez levei uma multa de trânsito aqui na cidade de São Paulo. No meu momento de ignorância cheguei até a postar um vídeo numa rede social tirando sarro da palavra **cincoenta**:

[image]

> *"CENTO E NOVENTA E UM REAIS E **CINCOENTA** E TRES CENTAVOS"*

Fiz algumas pesquisas na internet e muitas delas me apontaram que certa palavra não existe e que o correto seria **cinquenta**. Citaram inclusive que a palavra **quatorze** poderia ser substituída por **catorze**, mas com cinquenta isso não acontece.

Essa palavra pode ser escrita dessa forma? Há algo a respeito no português de Portugal ou de outros países?

Comment: Na ortografia do século 19, essa palavra existia; mas na ortografia atual, acho que "cincoenta" é errado em todos os países lusófonos. Veja a expressão "cincoenta cruzados" [neste exemplo que sublinhei](https://i.imgur.com/6mdfbYc.png). O conto "*Os três conselhos*" aparece numa coletânea de contos populares de Portugal publicada no século 19.

Comment: Também vi um documento de 1993 aonde consta a palavra cincoenta duas vezes, uma se referindo a tamanho e outra se referindo a valor.

Comment: Um erro ortográfico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vários sites e dicionários de diferentes países confirmam que `cincoenta` [é incorreto](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/cinquenta-cinquenta-ou-cincoenta/) já há bastante tempo.

A referência mais recente que encontro (numa busca cursiva) que lista a palavra é o [Novo Diccionário Da Língua Portuguesa (1913)](http://dicionario-aberto.net/dict.pdf) (também citado no [TheFreeDictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/Cincoenta)). E [Seninha](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/2076/seninha) aponta em seu comentário seu uso num conto português publicado no século 19 (figura abaixo).

Talvez exista uma pequena chance deste erro ter alguma relação com o hábito de preencher cheques com grafia propositalmente incorreta para os números (e.g., `hum` ao invés de `um`) numa suposta tentativa de dificultar falsificações.

[image]

Comment: Se não me engano, essa ortografia foi atualizada pela reforma ortográfica de 1911, pela qual "légoa" e "cincoenta" virou "légua" e "cinquenta"; com algumas exceções como "mágoa" e "páscoa".  Como que escrever errado dificultaria falsificações?

Comment: @Seninha, O argumento seria que dificultaria, e.g., transformar um "um" em "vinte e um", suponho que haja suficiente espaço em branco. Sobre ter sido numa das reformas, se você tiver uma referência, incluo na resposta.

Comment: [Item XX da reforma de 1911](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1911#20-toggle)

Comment: @Seninha, Sou leigo no assunto, mas não me sinto confiante na sua interpretação: para mim a frase de abertura do item XX, "*Continua o emprêgo tradicional de o átono valendo por u*", indica justamente que as exceções como as que você menciona são isso, exceções, que os 'o's em geral permanecem. Inclusive encontrei o dicionário que menciono de 1913 (http://dicionario-aberto.net/dict.pdf), cujo autor lista "cinquenta" como "Outra forma de *cincoenta* [...] pouco diffundida, embora exacta" - e "extravagante", pg. 9, o que pode por outro indicar que se trata de mera inércia frente à reforma...

Comment: Também sou leigo no assunto. Disse que "se não me engano foi pela reforma de 1911" porque os textos com "légoa", "lingoagem" e "cincoenta" foram desaparecendo (ao menos dos corpus em que pesquiso) pelas décadas de 10 e 20 do século passado, daí inferi ser por causa dessa reforma, que coincide com o início desse época; mas não tenho nenhuma certeza de que foi por isso mesmo, só reparei na coincidência. O uso de "o" em "cincoenta" tbm tem o agravante de se apoiar em "cinco", com o qual é morfologicamente relacionado, tal como "mágoa" se apoia em "magoar", o que explicaria sua persistência.

Comment: @Seninha, seria possível que nenhuma nova regra tenha tornado "cincoenta" incorreto, mas apenas o desuso? Isso significaria que ele é um arcaísmo, não uma incorreção.

Comment: Se é possível, sim. Se é caso, não sei. Mas em nenhum dicionário ou vocabulário ortográfico consta "cincoenta". Ainda que correto, já morreu por desuso.

Answer (score 0):

Estou lendo um livro nesse momento e fiquei curioso por que vi essa palavra escrita. O livro foi escrito escrito no idioma original no ano de 1939 e sua versão para o português lançada em 1987 onde é dito "cincoenta" várias vezes para ser tratar tamanho e também é utilizado Jardas como unidade de medida

Nome do livro : Um pouco de ar, por favor! Autor George Orwell edição 1987, página 79